# Distributing arbitrary union over arbitrary intersection (and vice versa)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Suppose $I, J$ are arbitrary index sets. Let $X$ be a set and $X_{i, j} \subseteq X$. I claim that
$$\bigcap_{i\in I} \bigcup_{j\in J} X_{i,j} = \bigcup_{(j_i) \in J^I}\: \bigcap_{i\in I} X_{i, j_i}.$$

$$\bigcup_{i\in I} \bigcap_{j\in J} X_{i,j} = \bigcap_{(j_i) \in J^I}\: \bigcup_{i\in I} X_{i, j_i}.$$

For the first result:
$\newcommand{\lra}{\longleftrightarrow}$
\begin{align*}
x \in \bigcap_{i\in I} \bigcup_{j\in J} X_{i,j} &\lra \forall i \in I\: \exists j \in J\: (x \in X_{i, j})\\
&\lra \exists (j_i) \in J^I \: \forall i \in I \: (x \in X_{i, j_i})\\
&\lra x \in \bigcup_{(j_i) \in J^I}\: \bigcap_{i\in I} X_{i, j_i}.
\end{align*}

For the second result, we employ the first combined with De Morgan's laws:

\begin{align*}
X - \bigcup_{i\in I} \bigcap_{j\in J} X_{i,j} &= \bigcap_{i\in I} \left[X-\bigcap_{j\in J} X_{i,j}\right]\\
&= \bigcap_{i\in I} \bigcup_{j\in J} (X - X_{i,j})\\
&= \bigcup_{(j_i) \in J^I}\: \bigcap_{i\in I} (X - X_{i,j_i})\\
&= \bigcup_{(j_i) \in J^I}\: \left[X - \bigcup_{i\in I} X_{i,j_i} \right]\\
&= X - \bigcap_{(j_i) \in J^I}\: \bigcup_{i\in I} X_{i,j_i}.
\end{align*}

Is this result true, and is my proof valid? I couldn't find such a general result on Google (only stuff about finite unions/intersections), so I wanted to double check.

Comment: Both results are true, and your proofs are spot-on.